# Получить предыдущую команду в консоли контейнера docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

На windows машине установлен docker-toolbox. 
Как только я захожу в контейнер, например: `docker exec -it web /bin/sh` я могу вводить там команды.

Как получить доступ к истории вводимых команд внутри контейнера? Во всех консолях это делается при помощи клавиши  "стрелочка вверх", здесь при нажатии на эту клавишу, появляется `^[[A`.

Как посмотреть историю или хотя бы вызывать предыдущую команду?

Comment: ctrl + p  попробуйте.

Comment: ничего не происходит

Comment: Ну вообще говоря я сейчас стянул контейнер с sh - действительно не умеет .
Вот тут об этом пишут.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21733/why-dont-my-arrow-keys-work-in-sh

Добавьте в контейнер bash , например. Ну или по ссылке там есть еще какие то примеры .